# How to get value from complex JObject? c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to see if there is an easier way to get a value by property name from JObject.

EDIT: "someProperty" in this case is a dynamic string property which changes.  In the below example, the property happens to fall under that token path.

```
// Convert object to Json, then to JObject
var process = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj));

// This seems highly uncessary, but it works
var myValue = process["Document"]["Process"]["Data"]["someProperty"];

// When I do the following I get null
var myValue = process["someProperty"].Value<string>();

// This also returns null
var myValue = process.GetValue("someProperty");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fastest and easiest way is to use dynamic

```
dynamic dyn = await GetStep(message.EventId);
var myValue = dyn.Document.Process.Data.someProperty ;
```

Alternatively you can use JPath

```
var process = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj));
JToken acme = o.SelectToken("$..someProperty"); // <-- less safe (multiple matches may occur)
```

Comment: This would work, but the problem is the property who's value needs obtained is dynamic.  "someProperty" changes.  I'll add an update for clarity

Comment: I updated my answer. please check it and IF you need another update I will do it accordingly